# Hibernate not maintaining persistance order

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I am working on import functionality where in i have to import data from a file and update it to the database using hibernate.

The object structure is : there is a parent and it has a Set of children.

When i do the import i first delete all the existing children and then add the new children i read from the file.

The way i do it is as below

```
parent = session.load(<id of parent>)  
parent.getchildrenSet.clear()  
parent.saveOrUpdate(parent);
```

Then, in a loop create new children and add it to the childrenSet on the parent. Then

```
parent.saveOrUpdate(parent);
```

Mappings are as below

In Parent

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "CHILD_TABLE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_PARENT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID") })
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "CHILD_ID")
    private Map<Long, Children> childrenMap;
```

In the Child

```
 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_PARENT_ID")
    private Parent parent;
```

**When i run this code i expected the logs to print the DMLs in the below order**
1. Delete all the children
2. Insert new children
3. Update the parent

**But what it prints is**
1. Insert new children
2. Update the parent
3. Delete all the children

So, as a result of the above order, it removes all the children from the parent, even the ones which i added newly because of import.

It seems like hibernate doesnt maintain the order in which i had called the DMLs. Can anyone provide me some suggestions on this? Let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: Could you try to do a [session.flush()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush%28%29) after the first saveOrUpdate()?

Comment: I referred other sources and found that using session.flush is not recommended.

Comment: flush is bad style. how do your mappings look?

Comment: added the mappings @ExpectoPatronum

Comment: Could I get a link that explains why it is not a good idea to use flush?

Comment: [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?32658-Setting-Hibernate-Flush-mode-in-spring)

Comment: @shashikanthb That links is about flush mode, not about calling session.flush(), I don't see how it applies here.

Comment: I was referring to this comment from the link "You shouldn't work with flushing too much since its behavior depends on the queries/database size at runtime.
If you want to take control however, you can work directly on the hibernate session by using a Hibernate callback for example (besides the hooks that karl already pointed out). ". But i guess you are right. Thanks @Pablo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections.clear() doesn't equate to delete. You need to call an explicit delete to ensure you delete before you insert. Else, the implicit delete will get exexuted when your session terminates.

Comment: thanks @Farhan, I'll try that. can u suggest me a good book which would help me understand Hibernate well

Comment: I learned a lot from the book "NHibernate in Action", I guess http://www.manning.com/bauer/ is also very good